# How to plot Radar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

Would you please show me how to do Radar plot with the following dataset.
In this dataset I want to see the distribution of **fut** column by the value
**total** and categorized by a variable called **Group** .
Here is the simulation data set

```
maxmin <- data.frame(
      total=c(5, 1,5,7),
      phys=c(15, 3, 9,3),
      psycho=c(3, 0,3,5),
      social=c(5, 1,4,6),
      env=c(5, 1,5,2),
      fut = c("am", "ber", "am", "ber"),
      group = rep(c("I", "M"), each = 2))
```

Thanks for your help!
Amare

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fmsb` package.

```
library(fmsb)
library(dplyr)
# Group names needs to be as row names of data.frame
x <- maxmin %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(fut, group, sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-c(fut, group))
df <- as.data.frame(x %>% select(-c(name)))
rownames(df) <- x$name
# max & min needs to be added as first and second row, respectively
df <- rbind(rep(20,5) , rep(0,5) , df)
par(mar=rep(0.8,4))
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
radarchart(df[c(1:2, 3:4), ], title = "I")
radarchart(df[c(1:2, 5:6), ], title = "M")
```

[resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut9o0.png)

EDIT:
Fol All in one:

```
## All in one
library(fmsb)
library(dplyr)
# Group names needs to be as row names of data.frame
x <- maxmin %>% 
  mutate(name = paste(fut, group, sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-c(fut, group))
df <- as.data.frame(x %>% select(-c(name)))
rownames(df) <- x$name
# max & min needs to be added as first and second row, respectively
df <- rbind(rep(20,5) , rep(0,5) , df)

radarchart(df,
           pcol = c("steelblue", "steelblue", "tomato", "tomato"), # colors define Group
           plty = c(1, 2, 1, 2), # line type defines fut
           plwd = 2) # line width
# Add a legend
legend(x=0.7, y=1, legend = rownames(df[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", pch=20 , col = c("steelblue", "steelblue", "tomato", "tomato"), text.col = "grey", cex=1.1, pt.cex=2)
```

[image: All in one]

**ADDED:** An example with new dataset:
For radarchart you need to have data.frame with variables in columns and groups in rows. Thus for your specific dataset `data` you need to create 3 separate plots (FClog, pvalue, count).
Here is the example for FClog:

```
#Example with new dataset "data"
library(fmsb)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(100) # you may want to set this for reproducibility example
data <- data.frame(da = c("total", "phys","psycho","social","fut", "total","phys", "psycho","social","fut"), logFC = runif(10, -1, 1), pvalue = runif(10, max= 0.05, min= 0.001), count = runif(10,max = 20, min = 12), group = rep(c("WT","KO"), each = 5))

x1 <- data %>% select(da, logFC, group) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = logFC) %>%
  as.data.frame()
rownames(x1) <- x1[,1]
x1 <- x1[,2:ncol(x1)]
x1 <- x1 %>%
  t() %>%
  as.data.frame()

# max & min needs to be added as first and second row, respectively
df <- rbind(rep(1,ncol(x1)) , rep(-1,ncol(x1)) , x1)
par(mar=rep(0.8,4))
radarchart(df,
           title = "FClog",
           pcol = c("steelblue", "tomato"), # colors define Group
           plty = c(1, 2), # line type defines fut
           plwd = 2) # line width
# Add a legend
legend(x=0.7, y=1, legend = rownames(df[-c(1,2),]), bty = "n", pch=20 , col = c("steelblue", "tomato"), text.col = "grey", cex=1.1, pt.cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks but can you able to put both in one Radar plot with a different color for "I" and "M". Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I think I gave a wrong simulation data for my problem. This new simulation data fits to my problem. I what to see the distribution of da across groups by absolute value of count. ´´´data <- data.frame(da = c("total", "phys","psycho","social","fut", "total","phys", "psycho","social","fut"), logFC = runif(10, -1, 1), pvalue = runif(10, max= 0.05, min= 0.001), count = runif(10,max = 20, min = 12), group = rep(c("WT","KO"), each = 5))´´´

Comment: I am not sure if radar chart is best for this type of data.
Anyhow, you need data.frame with variables as columns and groups as rows.Thus you need plot separate plot for each of your three extra variables. I added an example of one.

Comment: Thank you so much  Dear Matushiq! I think I got the solution now.